# How load IcoMoon webfont in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, icons

How load webfont in React?

1. added the 4 webfont to the public folder

[image]

2. created font-face

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "IcoMoon";
  src: url("/icons/line-icons-fonts/icomoon.eot");
  src: url("/icons/line-icons-fonts/icomoon.svg") format("svg"),
    url("/icons/line-icons-fonts/icomoon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/icons/line-icons-fonts/icomoon.woff") format("woff");
}
```

3. put a `div` in an `a`. Set `fontFamily`  and `className`. But icon does not appear, strange. I would use one of these icons.

https://themekit.dev/docs/code/iconsmind/

```js
<a
  href={`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=2773133082797983&display=popup&href=https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/${props.productId}&redirect_uri=https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/${props.productId}&hashtag=#bestGift&quote=EgyMondat`}
>
  <div
    style={{ fontFamily: "IcoMoon" }}
    className={"im-over-time2 text-lg"}
  ></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the `@font-face {...` manually, but you need to add the CSS file generated by IcoMoon to be able to use the font(s).

This is because the class names for the icons are defined in that `.css` file.

Currently in you case yes you added the fonts file, and declared a font-face but where is defined the CSS rules for you icon `im-over-time2` ?

The style.css file created by IcoMoon declare all the classes for the icons you selected, something like :

```css
.icon-blablabla:before {
  content: "\e91c";
}
.icon-youhou:before {
  content: "\e948";
}
.icon-foobar:before {
  content: "\e98d";
}
```